# blueprintjs Select Component onItemSelect Function Doesn't Run

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, blueprintjs

I'm just trying to output text to the console when I click on a MenuItem in the dropdown menu. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? There isn't much help on this topic besides the [example component](https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/blob/develop/packages/docs-app/src/examples/select-examples/selectExample.tsx) in the docs.

```
 itemRenderer(item) {
    return (
      <MenuItem
        key={item.id}
        label={item.year}
        text={item.season}
        shouldDismissPopover={true}
      />
    )
  }

  handleclick(item) {
    //this never runs :(
    console.log('clicked')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Select
        items={this.state.semesters}
        filterable={false}
        itemRenderer={this.itemRenderer}
        onItemSelect={this.handleclick}
      >
        <Button text={'Select a Semester'} rightIcon="caret-down" />
      </Select>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add a click handler on each `MenuItem`:

```js
  itemRenderer(item, {handleClick}) {     // added {handleClick} argument
    return (
      <MenuItem
        key={item.id}
        label={item.year}
        text={item.season}
        onClick={handleClick}             // added this line
        shouldDismissPopover={true}
      />
    )
  }
```

Check CodeSandbox demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/3rplzz746m (open the console)

Comment: Saved me half a day I guess, there's no error or warning. I'm going to propose adding an FAQs section on their repo.